# Getting 502 Bad gateway error while using facebook webhook for leadgen in asp.net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get facebook leads in Asp.Net Web Api by following this guide - https://medium.com/@somaraj/retrieving-facebook-lead-ads-using-asp-net-web-api-and-graph-api-web-hooks-70f6dd8bba4a

i have got all the permissions for leadgen and this is my Callback Url https://testing.harishparas.com/api/webhooks ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps05z.png)
and here i have used the Verify token same as the User token i have used in Post Api my Url is verified successfully but when i'm hitting it on the Postman it says [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sibde.png)
502 error in the Post Api and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdf8X.png)
500 Internal Error in the Get Api, i don't know where to set or pass the value of hub.challenge as i'm not setting it anywhere so Can you help me out with this please that what to do next to get the leadgen data in the Api.
Thanks in advance.

#region Get Request

[HttpGet]

public HttpResponseMessage Get()

```
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"])
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
        return response;
    }
```

#endregion Get Request

```
    #region Post Request

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] JsonData data)
    {
        try
        {
            var entry = data.Entry.FirstOrDefault();
            var change = entry?.Changes.FirstOrDefault();
            if (change == null) return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            //Generate user access token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
            const string token = "*************";

            var leadUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{change.Value.LeadGenId}?access_token={token}";
            var formUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{change.Value.FormId}?access_token={token}";

            using (var httpClientLead = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await httpClientLead.GetStringAsync(formUrl);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                {
                    var jsonObjLead = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeadFormData>(response);
                    //jsonObjLead.Name contains the lead ad name

                    //If response is valid get the field data
                    using (var httpClientFields = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        var responseFields = await httpClientFields.GetStringAsync(leadUrl);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseFields))
                        {
                            var jsonObjFields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeadData>(responseFields);
                            //jsonObjFields.FieldData contains the field value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine($"Error-->{ex.Message}");
            //Console.WriteLine($"StackTrace-->{ex.StackTrace}");
            Trace.WriteLine($"Error-->{ex.Message}");
            Trace.WriteLine($"StackTrace-->{ex.StackTrace}");
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you host the API on local machine and call from post man does it work fine?

Comment: You need to pass `hub.challenge` as a query string parameter in API url

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes it works fine on local machine or get hit by Postman on local

Comment: Can you tell me that when i"m passing the Verify Token during Subscribing should i use that token anywhere in the Api Code and if Yes then Where?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya where can I get this hub.challenge parameter value